# Ordering polygon neighbors in clockwise order using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, adjacency

In ArcMap, I am using the Polygon Neighbors tool to generate a list of each polygon's adjacent polygons, or 'neighbors.' Currently, ArcMap orders the polygons using each polygon's numeric ID. What I would like to do is order each polygon's neighbor list in clockwise order relative to the center of the "source" polygon.

For example, in the picture below, if Polygon 1 is my source precinct, the neighbors currently appear ordered 2,3,4,5,6,7. I would like the ordering to be clockwise - say, 6,3,7,5,4,2. (The start of the list does not matter, only that they are clockwise relative to the starting neighbor in the list.)

Is there a way to do this in ArcMap?

[image: Example of Polygon Neighbors]

Comment: That looks like a random ordering to me.  You can of course construct whatever attribute allocation scheme you want, but first you need to choose a programming environment, and then start programming.

Comment: Hi, @Vince. For clarification, which ordering are you saying looks random?

Comment: To do this I would try ArcPy and look at the angles between the centroid of the centre polygon and each of its neighbours.

Comment: @PolyGeo, that's what I originally did. However, due to the irregular shapes of some of the polygons and the placement of their centroids, the order sorted by angles does not correspond to the clockwise order in many cases. Too many to fix manually, at least.

Comment: What about the angles between the centroid of the centre polygon and the points where it intersects each pair of neighbours?  If that does not work then assembling a list of the coordinates where the centre polygon intersects each pair of its neighbours, and then examining them against each coordinate in the string of coordinates that make up the polygon should let you write a new list in the clock-wise order.

Comment: @PolyGeo That was my initial thought - using the point of intersection with pairs of neighbors - but is there a straightforward way to generate those points in ArcMap? There are a LOT of polygons in my map, so it's not possible to do manually.

Comment: Perhaps ask that as a new question: "Making point from node which makes polygons node neighbours?"  I think the answer to that will be to use the Intersect tool.

Comment: Extract polygon edges, compute midpoints and their chainage along outline of one in a center. This will be a field to base your ordering on. No scripting.

Comment: @FelixIP, do you know of any resources that would walk through how to do those things in ArcMap? I'm struggling to figure out how to do the method you suggested, though I agree it should work.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

This workflow will create mid points of edges between polygons and delete outer ones called `"LINKS"`:

```py
arcpy.FeatureToLine_management(in_features="PGONS", out_feature_class="C:/SCRATCH/OUTLINES.shp", cluster_tolerance="", attributes="NO_ATTRIBUTES")
arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features="OUTLINES", out_feature_class="C:/SCRATCH/edges.shp", dissolve_field="", statistics_fields="", multi_part="SINGLE_PART", unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(in_features="edges", out_feature_class="C:/SCRATCH/midpoints.shp", point_location="MID")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features="midpoints", join_features="PGONS", out_feature_class="C:/SCRATCH/SJ.shp", join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY")
arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features="SJ", out_feature_class="C:/SCRATCH/links.shp", dissolve_field="TARGET_FID", statistics_fields="JOIN_FID FIRST;JOIN_FID LAST", multi_part="SINGLE_PART", unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view="links", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause='"FIRST_JOIN" = "LAST_JOIN_"')
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(in_features="links")
```

I thought to continue that way, but realised, that I don't know how to compute chainage on a closed line using linear referencing and I don't know model builder good enough to loop through polygons. So here you go:

```py
import arcpy, os
import networkx as nx

nodes="PGONS"
edges="LINKS"
G=nx.Graph()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(edges, ("Shape@","FIRST_JOIN","LAST_JOIN_")) as cursor:
    for pG,f,t in cursor:
        G.add_edge(f,t)
        G[f][t]["Shape"] = pG
g = arcpy.Geometry()
geometryList = [pgon.boundary() for pgon in arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(nodes,g)]
curT = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("out_points",("F","T","SHAPE@"))
for f in G.nodes():
    outline = geometryList[f]
    aList = []
    for t in nx.neighbors(G,f):
        p = G[f][t]["Shape"].firstPoint
        chainage = outline.measureOnLine(p)
        aList.append((chainage,f,t,p))
    aList.sort()
    for chainage,f,t,p in aList:
        curT.insertRow((f,t,p))
del curT
```

Output:

[image]

I connected some of the output points:

[image]

Note: tested on shapefiles.